# When I ping a site, sometimes it uses IP v4 and other times IP v6. Why?

Tags: networking, ip, routing, ping

These Pings were done at different times of the same day:

C:\Users\LPress>ping www.ucla.edu
Pinging gateway.lb.it.ucla.edu [164.67.228.152] with 32 bytes of data:

C:\Users\LPress>ping www.ucla.edu
Pinging gateway.lb.it.ucla.edu [2607:f010:2e8:228:0:ff:fe00:152] with 32 bytes of data:

Comment: The site your are pinging has multiple IP addresses ...

Answer (score 0):

That is just how DNS works.

When a DNS entry has more than one ip addresses, it will at random pick one that the client supports and use that. In your case, the DNS has an ip address for IPv4 and an ip address for IPv6. Your client both has support for IPv4 and IPv6, so it will pick either of them.

Once a connection is established, it will keep using that protocol until the connection is dropped. Given that a ping is a really short connection, it can change upon the next ping.

Do note, this is not a proven method for failover connectivity. Some clients will always pick the first entry, some always the last, and some just randomly pick one.

Comment: If there is an IP4 and an IP6, why not always pick the IP6?

Comment: Because your device supports both, and your client basically randomly takes whatever DNS gives back.